# Using `memcpy()` to assign a pointer an address

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memcpy

Is

```
memcpy( ptr, &value, sizeof(char *) );
```

the same as

```
ptr = &value;
```

.....

I've never seen `memcpy()` used to do this before.
It seems like I should respond to the developer of this code with the phrase "Well, you're not wrong." It seems like a bit wordier than it needs to be.

Edit: It seems important to note that `ptr` is `void * ptr`. `value` is `double value`.

---

Edit2: For those who are interested in following this problem down its rabbit hole with me read along.  This bit of code was flagged by static analysis as a potential buffer overflow.  The static analysis was worried that the destination buffer `ptr` might not have enough space to hold a `sizeof(char *)` worth of information.
Rather than deal with the problem it gave me I tried to understand exactly what this `memcpy()` did (thank you for helping me with that).  Once I understood what was happening, I had to understand why the size of memory given to `memcpy()` was `sizeof(char *)`; the function this `memcpy()` is in is called one time, and that one time it looks like this:

```
SdmJniGetPointer(blah, blah, &ptr)
```

Meaning that the actual value of `ptr` within this function, and in the `memcpy()` call, is the address of another pointer!

It was bizzare to me that the previous developer would `memcpy()` a `sizeof(char *)` amount of data because this system is compiled on 32 and 64 bit machines.  However, because he passes in the address to a pointer (`&ptr`) into the function as `ptr`, he not only circumvents this shifting from 4-byte pointers to 8-byte pointers depending on the system architecture but wields it exactly as he meant too (I think).  In the end, on a 64-bit system, all of the `double value` is copied into the address pointed to by `ptr` which is really an address to a different pointer (`&ptr`), and on 32-bit machines, half of it is copied to the location `ptr` which is really `&ptr`.  Now I just need to figure out what that `double value` really represents, and why he would be ok bisecting it.

If that didn't make sense, I'll try again, but it feels a like he was Inception-ing the pointer. =)

Comment: Assuming the types check out, I believe that is valid. Just remember that the first statement won't typecheck like the second one will, so type errors will slip through if the first statement is used.

Comment: No that's not the same. `memcpy` copies the data pointed to by the source pointer to the address pointed to by the destination pointer. `ptr` will still point to the same address afterwards.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Maybe that is why it written that way.  I think someone was trying to dodge the type checker.

Comment: @Makenbaccon: That's what casts are for. At worst, use pointer casts; they are still much more readable than this crap

Comment: They can't be the same. The first one copies into what `ptr` points to, the other changes the value of `ptr`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It's actually `*(char *)ptr = (char *)&value` No idea how `double` fits into this.

Comment: @Olaf kind of odd, isn't it?

Comment: @Olaf I guess I need to figure out if he was trying to copy the value of the `double` into where `ptr` is pointing, or if he wanted the address of the `double` copied into `ptr`.  Whichever he intended, he seemed to do neither.

Comment: sizeof(double) is not guaranteed to be the same as sizeof(char*), insofar saying "Well, you're not wrong" is wrong. It may work ("work") but it's initializing a pointer with a non-safely derived pointer by overwriting the raw bit pattern. In other words, undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changes the **address** that the pointer `ptr` points to:

```
ptr = &value;
```

This changes the **data** at the address that the pointer `ptr` points to:

```
memcpy(ptr, &value, sizeof(char*));
```

In the second case, `ptr` still points to the same address as before the call. So in no way are they the same.

Comment: "This changes the address of the pointer"? Ehm.. it changes its value.

Comment: This has been closest to helping me understand; just so that I make sure i get it...`memcpy()` goes to the address pointed to by `ptr`, then writes `sizeof(char *)` bytes from the address pointed to by `&value` to the address pointed to by `ptr`, correct?

Comment: @Olaf You're right, badly phrased - lack of coffee is my excuse.

Comment: @Makenbaccon Correct. `memcpy` effectively dereferences both of the pointers you provide - it doesn't change the pointers themselves.

Comment: I guess now I need to figure out what the previous developer actually wanted to do...hmmm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is absolutely different.  Let's add some types:

```
char *addr;
char **ptr = &addr;
char *value = "Hello";

memcpy(ptr, &value, sizeof(char *));
// Equivalent to...
*ptr = value;
```

Better to avoid `memcpy()` if it is possible to use `=` instead.

Among other things, if the types are incorrect, then `=` will generate the proper diagnostics, while `memcpy()` will happily crash your program or worse.

Given the types,

```
double value, value2;
void *ptr = &value2;

// This copies `value` into `value2`.
memcpy(ptr, &value, sizeof(double));
```

Using `sizeof(char *)` is wrong, because it should be `sizeof(double)` if you are copying a `double`.

Theoretically, you could be doing something more esoteric, but I'll ignore that possibility.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your example.  I've made an edit, would you be able to readdress your answer?

Comment: @Makenbaccon: I've already updated this answer in response to your edit.

Comment: =) thanks. I'll respond to your edit: if `value` is a double, `&value` is a `double *`, correct? To be most acurate, it should be `sizeof(double *)`, correct?

Comment: No, that's incorrect.  If `value` is `double`, then `&value` is `double *`, and you should `memcpy(..., sizeof(double))`.

Comment: It is definitely something more esoteric.  I think whatever value that `double` is holding isn't really a `double`, I think the previous developer just needed a `double` sized word.

Answer (score 1):

That `memcpy` is like

```
*ptr = value;
```

So `ptr` has to point to a `char *` (assuming `value` is, according to the `sizeof`).

Assuming `ptr` is `char **` (or you change that to take the address of `ptr`: `&ptr`) and properly initialized, I see no actual problem **here**. However, this code inhibits type checking by the compiler and is likely slower than a simple assignment.

It also might exhibit problems with aliasing if source and destination have different typs (as the edit implies). It also will likely prohibit optimizations.

Oh, and: that code is more difficult to read/manually verify/understand, IOW: to maintain (as the comments and my own edits show). Maybe the developer was after job safety by obfuscation?

**Edit:**

After your edit adding type information: That code is even worse. It does not even use the same types. My advise: kick the author where it really hurts and then rewrite the code *very* carefully. Note: whoever write such code, very likely writes more crap elsewhere.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: You are right, thanks. I just read `&ptr`. Updated my answer. (Who writes such crap?)

Comment: Ya, I've been hired to fix this code.  The problem is that I've been told its already working.  I need to determine what he was doing here so I don't screw it up

Comment: Oh, my! I know that. Had such a job myself: "The code is almost complete, just some additions required". It ended up 1 year work for code which I had rewritten in half the time more clearly and with much less collywobbles. Pro-side: I'm a freelancer - longer safe income :-)

Comment: no, it's like `*ptr = value;`  . `memcpy` takes the address of both source and destination. `value` must have type `char *` and `ptr` have type `char **` (although you could argue that `void *` would work). There's no aliasing problem if those were the types (although they aren't as OP's edit shows)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You're right. Just edited. That is apparently more confusing that I thought. Even more reason not to use this. Regarding aliasing: I just remember about some question some days ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

The assignment notation is much more concise and readable then using memcpy and allows compiler optimization.  The `=` means an assignment, while memcpy just copies memory.
*You should stick with the `=` assignment*